# How do I deal with optional columns when constructing a prepared statement

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I would like to leverage a prepared statement in order to insert/update postgres db.
The thing is that the table contains nullable columns I might or might not have a value for in runtime.
In case I do not have anything to insert/update , I need the old value to remain.
Is there a syntax I can use for that case?
What are the best practices in cases like that, it seems like a very common problem?

P.S
I use java/scala with plain jdbc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, of course, just construct a statement without the columns you don't want to update.

If this isn't an option in your usecase, you could construct a case expression with a "flag" to indicate if the column should be bound or not.

E.g.:

```
String sql = "UPDATE mytable " +
             "SET " +
             "col1 = CASE(? WHEN 1 THEN ? ELSE col1 END), " +
             "col2 = CASE(? WHEN 1 THEN ? ELSE col2 END) " +
             "WHERE id = ?";

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

// col1 should be updated
ps.setInt(1, 1);
ps.setString(2, newValueCol1);

// col2 should not be updated
ps.setInt(3, 0);
ps.setString(4, null); // or any other value...

// bind the where clause
ps.setInt(5, someId);

ps.executeUpdate();

// close resources and clean up, omitted for brevity's sake
```

Comment: Thanks. The flag option looks like exactly what I needed.
Would it work for insert statement as well?

Comment: I meant inserting a default value when no value is provided.

Comment: @EliGolin you could use the `case` expression in a `values` clause of an `insert` statement.

Comment: Good for SQL case usage but  in this case, more than in another, NamedParameterStatement would be better.  In your example, it's error prone

Comment: @davidhxxx true, but note that this isn't a plain JDBC class. It may not be a valid solution for the OP.